# Avoid Cross Joins in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, cross-join

I have 2 tables T1 and T2.

**T1**:

```
ID  |   Name                              
----+-------
A   |   A1                                
A   |   C1
```

**T2**:

```
ID   | Name
-----+------
A    | A1
A    | B1
```

I want to retrieve records that have same ID and Name with flag 1 and Same ID and Different Name with flag 0. However, while joining the table in SQL Server, I am getting the a cross join which is:

```
A | A1 | A1 | 1                 
A | A1 | B1 | 0  
A | C1 | A1 | 0  
A | C1 | B1 | 0
```

But I need the answer as:

```
A | A1 | A1 | 1     
A | C1 | B1 | 0
```

The above result is giving me the same information about name mismatch but in limited no. of rows and no repetition.

Could somebody let me know how can do this in SQL Server?

Comment: The output in the first grid above is correct based on the specifications you gave. You need to clarify the rules that define what is returned. Perhaps something like "I want to retrieve records that match based on ID and Name with a flag 1." (this part is simple). "For all remaining records, they should be matched across the two databases,"(?)

Comment: If your data elements in T1 were A | A1 |, A | C1 |, and B | A1|, but the entries in T2 were like they are now, what should be returned?

Comment: Also, if T1 contained A | A1 |, A | C1 |, and A | B1 |, what would the output be?

Comment: Please provide your SQL-code, in the moment the question is too general.

Comment: Think of the two cases you've explained. Solve the first case using not by using a join, by by using `WHERE EXISTS`. This ensures that you get the same or less rows for the first case. Now repeat for the second case and `UNION ALL` them together. Try that and _post the SQL code that you attempted_

Comment: Just an observation that ID is short for identifier (i.e. a "[symbol which uniquely identifies an object or record](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID)"); but in this scenario there are two rows on the same table with the same value for ID. And that is the case for both tables. I suggest renaming those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Name Name1, T2.Name Name2, case T1.Name when T2.Name then 1 else 0 end Result
from T1
inner join T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
where T1.Name = T2.Name
    or (not exists (select 1 from T2 where T1.Name = Name and T1.ID = ID)
        and not exists (select 1 from T1 where T2.Name = Name and T2.ID = ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a union to keep things simple:

```
select T1.ID, T1.Name Name1, T2.Name Name2, 1 flag
from T1
join T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
and T1.Name = T2.Name
union all
select T1.ID, T1.Name, T2.Name, 0
from T1
join T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
and T1.Name != T2.Name
```

Using a union is not *the* most efficient way, but it’s much easier to understand and unless you have millions of rows, it will still run very fast (and `union all` is quite a bit faster than `union`)

Comment: This query returns all four rows (including A1 | B1 and C1 | A1). OP only wanted rows A1 | A1 and C1 | B1 returned.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ROW_NUMBER` and `FULL JOIN`

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID VARCHAR(5),   Name VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('A', 'A1')
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES('A', 'C1')

DECLARE @T2 TABLE (ID VARCHAR(5),   Name VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('A', 'A1')
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('A', 'B1')


SELECT T1.ID, T1.Name, T2.Name, CASE WHEN T1.Name = T2.Name THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM 
    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Name) AS RN, * FROM @T1 ) T1
    FULL JOIN 
    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Name) AS RN, * FROM @T2 ) T2 
        ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.RN = T2.RN
```

Result:

```
ID    Name  Name  
----- ----- ----- -----------
A     A1    A1    1
A     C1    B1    0
```